# SQL statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using a simple SQL statement in JS running on server.
The statement is

```
SELECT Record FROM RecordMap
```

Here I plugin the "Map" word from a variable. Upon executing this query inside a try/catch, I get an error logged from the caught exception - Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.

I execute the same query using SQL+ and it returns the correct result.

The code snippet is pasted below. (Log function just logs the passed string to a txt file. I am using it to debug this error)

(I am using MS SQL Server 2005 on the local machine)

```
        var sqlText = "SELECT Record FROM " + batch[i].map;
        Log(sqlText);
        var Record = "";     
        try
        {
            var rs = sqlConnection.Execute( sqlText );
            if ( !rs.EOF )
            {
                if(rs(1).value != null)  Record = rs(1).value; 
            }
        }
        catch(x)
        {
            Log(x.message);
        }
        rs.close();
```

Comment: I don't know what populates `batch[i].map`, but this smells of SQL injection waiting to happen.

Comment: What technologies are you using? I don't think that's the syntax for node.js, and I don't recognize what this could be. Also, isn't SQL+ an Oracle product, not SQL Server? One thought, most indexers are zero-based, not one-based, so maybe `rs(1)` should be `rs(0)`.

Comment: This is Jscript. I also thought about indexes starting from 0, but it doesn't work.
The SQL+ I am using is a proprietary product used to query to any database directly.

Comment: Just a guess: do you have to advance `rs` to the first record as it is positioned before the first record after executing the SQL?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I have done client side coding.

However, ordinal position usually means you are trying to reference rs(x) where x is out of bounds.  Are you sure the record set is one or zero based.

Also, do a print of the sqlText to make sure you are passing to SQL Server the correct T-SQl.

Cheers